# Solve $2\cos 2x - 5\cos x-4=0$ for $0 <x <2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm new to addition and double angle formula so please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: **HINT**: You could use the identity:$$\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)-1$$to reduce this to a quadratic in $\cos(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, so your equation is equivalent to

$$2\left(2\cos^2 x-1\right)-5\cos x-4=0$$

$$\iff 4\cos^2 x-5\cos x-6=0,$$

which is a quadratic equation in terms of $\cos x$.

You'll get $\cos x\in\left\{-\frac{3}{4},2\right\}$. But by the definition of $\cos x$ we have $\cos x\in[-1,1]$, so $\cos x=-\frac{3}{4}$ is the only possibility, giving you the only solution $x=\pm\arccos \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\pi k$, where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Since you need $0<x<2\pi$, your answer is either $x=\arccos \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)$ or $x=-\arccos\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

We see that if we use the double-angle identity cos(2x) = 2cos^2(x) - 1 to turn all terms into multiples and powers of cos(x). Doing so, we obtain 4cos^2(x) - 5cos(x) - 6 = 0. Factoring, we get (4cos(x) + 3)(cos(x) - 2) = 0. This means that cos(x) = -3 / 4 or 2. The cosine of x cannot equal 2, so cos(x) = -3 / 4. On the interval (0, 2pi), x = cos^(-1)(-3 / 4), which is about 139 degrees or 2.419 radians and 221 degrees or 3.864 radians.